# <h:form> appears in a new line

Tags: jsf, newline, forms

I want to add redirection link into text. I tried this

**JSF page**

```
Learn <h:form><h:commandLink value="more" actionListener="#{pageredirect.redirectToPartnerForm()}"/></h:form> about channel and alliance partner
```

**JSF Bean**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Pageredirect implements Serializable
{
    public void redirectToPartnerForm() throws IOException
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("partner_opportunity_profile.xhtml");
    }
}
```

This is the visual result:

```
Learn
more
about channel and alliance partner opportunities.
```

I don't understand why the text "more" is on new line. How I can fix this?

Comment: Look at the client-side generated HTML

Comment: Can you propose some solution?

Comment: Use CSS. By the way, why not just <h:link>? Why POST instead of GET for page-to-page navigation? If I'm not mistaken you was been told this several times before. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15521451

Comment: Or put the form around the entire sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.